# xpath to pull every descendant beside the nested target tag

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

I have xml file looking like this:

```
<root>

  <a>
    <b> test </b>
      <a> test 2</a>

      <c> test 3 </c>
     <d> test4 </d>
     <e> test5
        <f> test6 </f>
        </e>
    </a>

</root>
```

is there any xpath 1.0 to catch every descendant of `<a>` except the nested `<a>`?
I've tried something like :

```
//a/*[not(self::a)]

//a/descendant::*
```

Comment: What exactly is your desired output? `test`?

Comment: yes, but this is only sample so besides <b> there are more tag, also inside the <b> which I'd like to catch

Comment: So please edit your question with a more representative sample of the html (not too long, though...) and the exact output expected from that.

Comment: I've added the updated sample, it should be everything besides "test 2"

Comment: Looks like your first attempt (`//a/*[not(self::a)`]
) works (at least on the html in the question).

Comment: @JackFleeting - That xpath doesn't actually select `f` specifically (which is a child of `e` that does get selected).

Comment: @katastari-dev - Did my answer help or are you still having issues?

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt of `//a/*[not(self::a)]` was close.

The issue is that you're matching child elements of `a`.

Try this instead:

```xml
//a//*[not(self::a)]
```